# Does Azure standard load balancer with HA port enabled support load balancing L3 transparent devices

Tags: azure, load-balancing

Looking to load balance two L3 transparent devices, that means the destination IP hitting the Azure LB could be anything. Would the LB accept that traffic and then forward it to the backend pool which is comprised of virtual appliances acting as transparent L3 devices?

Answer (score -1):

Just confirmed, it is possible. Use UDR to force traffic, and turn on Direct Server Return and HA ports.